# Check to see if NGINX is installed on UBUNTU

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nginx

Is there any or command to check whether NGINX is already installed on UBUNTU Linux using a bash command/script?

I was trying something like this

```
echo "BEGINNING INSTALLATION OF NGINX WEB SERVER"
echo
echo
echo "CHECKING TO SEE IF NGINX IS ALREADY INSTALLED"
service nginx > temp.install 2> temperr.install
echo 111
grep -c unrecognized temperr.install > temp2.install
echo 222
status = `cat temp2.install`
echo "NGINX STATUS $status"
```

Am new to bash scripting and hence not sure if this is teh best possible way to approach this. I need to write a script that checks if NGINX is already installed or not. If it is not installed it simply installs NGINX otherwise it first deletes NGINX and then re-installs it.

Comment: How about `dpkg -l | grep nginx`

Comment: I tried this but it just returns back to the bash prompt without giving me any output.

Comment: @op Check return status with `echo $?` right after issuing the `dpkg` command.

Comment: Well... did not check return status but I just modified your command a bit and it works for me. This is what I did dpkg -l | grep -c nginx . If nginx is installed it returns the count of the nginx packages and if it is not installed it simply returns 0

Answer (score 12):

```
if ! which nginx > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Nginx not installed"
fi
```

or

```
if [ ! -x /usr/sbin/nginx ]; then
    echo "Nginx not installed"
fi
```

or if you want to be Debian/Ubuntu specific:

```
if ! dpkg -l nginx | egrep 'îi.*nginx' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Nginx not installed"
fi
```

if you're into the whole brevity thing:

```
! test -x /usr/sbin/nginx && echo "Nginx not installed"
```

Comment: Just the little caveat that this only finds if nginx is installed the standard way. not if it is compiled from source and installed in for instance /usr/local/bin

Comment: The last answer is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
command -v nginx
```

install if not installed:

```
command -v nginx || sudo apt install nginx
```

Comment: `command` is not found in cron job, I am not able to find full path for `command`, ie using which command

Answer (score 0):

I build below solution, which run also in cron job

```
ISNGINX_INSTALLED=`/bin/ls /usr/sbin/nginx`
if [[ ! -z $ISNGINX_INSTALLED ]]; then
    echo "NOT installed"
else
    echo "installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go cleaner like this:

```
# create function
function ensure_nginx(){
  if [ -x "$(command -v nginx)" ]; then
      echo "Nginx already installed. Skipping installation..."
  else
      echo "Installing nginx..."
      sudo apt update
      sudo apt install nginx -y
      sudo ufw app list
      echo "Nginx installed!"
  fi
}

# call it
ensure_nginx
```